# nocurrentpoint exception PostScript

Tags: postscript

I developed a function to make a simple checkbox in postscript, but still it seems to not work.
There is no problem to generate the rectangle, but it seems to throw an exception during the writing of the lines (making the classical X of the checkbox).

```
/nocurrentpoint in --nocurrentpoint--
```

Here's my code.

```
/doMarkedCheckBox {
0.1 setlinewidth
currentpoint
/yIniChk exch def
/xIniChk exch def
xIniChk 
yIniChk
DimChars
DimChars
rectstroke
xIniChk DimChars add yIniChk DimChars add lineto 
0 DimChars 0 sub moveto 
yIniChk DimChars add xIniChk lineto 
stroke
} bind def
```

Can someone explain how to do it correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a procedure definition, where do you call the procedure? the `currentpoint` only is valid when you did a `moveto` before (or any other command that sets the current point). There is no current point before you set one yourself. (Translating or other transformations do not set the current point neither)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is exactly the problem - after the  `rectstroke` call you close the path and is left with no starting point.

You can just move there again, putting the values on the stack and issuing `moveto`  - there seems to be at least an error on the code to generate the other part of the check as well - and, since you have the squaresize in `DimChars` already, it may be easier to use `rlineto` in these issues.

All in all, if you replace your instructions after `rectstroke` by this sequence you should be good:

```
    ...
    xInitChk YInitChk moveto
    DimChars DimChars rlineto
    stroke
    XInitChk YInitChk DimChars add moveto
    DimChars DimChars neg rlineto
    stroke
} bind def
```